# Low level tcp socket

Tags: c, socket, tcp, unix

Since I am a Unix newbie, I wanted to know if the code reflects the "unix" style and if there is something to add for it to be robust.

P. S. I hope I am not overusing `assert` calls.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define whaterror strerror(errno)
#define PORT 0xbb8
#define BACKLOG 0xf // can't be > 128. 
#define BUFFSIZE 0x400

void init_server(struct sockaddr_in* server)
{
    assert(server != NULL && "Server pointer can't be null");

    server -> sin_family = AF_INET; // use IP.
    server -> sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // listen on any address (0.0.0.0).
    server -> sin_port = htons(PORT); // listen on PORT.
}

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sock_in; // an inbound socket
    const int sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // try to open the socket.
    assert(sockfd >= 0 && "Error in opening socket."); // check if socket opened.
    memset((char*)&sock_in, 0, sizeof(sock_in)); // reset sock_in to 0

    init_server(&sock_in); // initialize server struct
    assert(
        bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr*)&sock_in, sizeof(sock_in)) >= 0 &&
        "Port binding failed."
    );
    assert(
        listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == 0 &&
        "Can't listen to the socket specified."
    );

    int bytes = 0;
    char* chunk = memset(malloc(BUFFSIZE), 0, BUFFSIZE);
    const int asocfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, 0);
    assert(asocfd >= 0 && "Error in accepting socket."); // check if socket opened.

    do {
        bytes = recv(asocfd, chunk, BUFFSIZE - 1, 0);
        memset(bytes == -1 ? chunk : chunk + bytes, 0, BUFFSIZE);
        !errno ?
            bytes && printf("%d\n%s\n", bytes, chunk)
            : fprintf(stderr, "ERRNO: %d [%s]\n", errno, whaterror);
    } while (errno == EAGAIN | bytes > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I hope I am not overusing `assert` calls

You do. `assert` is a debugging instrument. If `NDEBUG` macro is defined, the calls to `assert` are removed at the compile time. This is a usual practice for the production code.

- `#define whaterror strerror(errno)`

  I advise against it. The macro adds no value, and only obfuscates the code.
- `memset(malloc`

  Keep in mind that `malloc` may fail.
- `memset(bytes == -1 ? chunk : chunk + bytes, 0, BUFFSIZE);`

  Setting `BUFFSIZE` bytes to 0 writes beyond the allocated space. You need `BUFFSIZE - bytes`.

  On the other hand, clearing the entire tail of the `chunk` is not necessary. `chunk[bytes] = 0;` is enough.
- `!errno ?`, besides being another obfuscation, is quite wrong. `errno` is a way to *inspect* errors, not to *detect* them. In fact, quoting `man errno`,

  > Successful calls never set errno; once set, it remains until another error occurs.

  `recv` returning `-1` *is* one and only indication of error.
- Since the socket is not marked nonblocking, it may never return `EAGAIN`. On the other hand, some errors are transient, and should not break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are definitely overusing, and **misusing** `assert()`.  The problem is that it is something that should become a no-op when your code is compiled for release.  As such, it should have NO side effects (like calling `bind()` or `listen()`, and should not be used for testing environmental errors.  `assert()` should only be used for testing for programming errors.  This means the use of `assert()` in `init_server()` is valid, but the rest aren't.
2. Your read loop is a bit twisted.  I might write it like:

   ```c
   for (;;) {
       bytes = recv(asocfd, chunk, BUFFSIZE, 0);
       if (bytes < 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "ERRNO: %d [%s]\n", errno, whaterror);
           if (errno != EAGAIN) break;
       } else if (bytes == 0) {
           break;
       } else {
           printf("%d\n%.*s\n", bytes, bytes, chunk)
       }
   }
   ```

   Among other issues there:

   - Your `memset()` call overran your buffer, quite possibly by the entire length of the buffer.
   - Your `memset()` was unneeded if there was an error.
   - `memset()` is excessive just to add a single trailing NUL.  It could have been written `chunk[bytes] = 0;`  This is actually why you included the  `- 1` in the `recv()` call.  (I removed the `- 1` as telling `printf()` not to go past the length is equally effective.
   - Don't avoid `if` statements.